# Resend messages from RabbitMQ works strange

Tags: rabbitmq, docker

I have RabbitMQ cluster in docker images. RabbitMQ have 1 exchange "EventExchange" and 2 queues: "QueueWait" and "QueueAction". Queues configured for resend:

- x-dead-letter-exchange: EventExchange
- x-dead-letter-routing-key: QueueAction
- durable: true

And consumer listens QueueAction.

**Logic**

1. Message is inserted into queue QueueWait with variable expiration time
2. After expiration message is moved from QueueWait to QueueAction
3. Consumer listening QueueAction got message

**Problem**

Today I had problem. Expired messages are not moved between QueueWait and QueueAction. But if I get all messages from QueueWait in default GUI of RabbitMQ they will be moved to the  QueueAction succesfully

**Environment**

- Image of docker - May be it is docker problem?
- RabbitMQ 3.2.4, Erlang R16B03

UPD:

I have to set TTL on the message level, because I have variable expiration dependet on the attempts of resend. How will I able to save current logic with guaranteed  resend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl-caveats

RabbitMQ expires messages when they reach the head of the queue, so if you don't have consumers, most probably your messages won't get expired.

Comment: I missed this caveats, tnx. But I need for TTL of messages (not queue), because I have to increase interval between resends of one message.